# Scroll positioned div using buttons jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a positioned div inside a few others (nested for design purposes) and would like some buttons to control the scroll position

Here is the HTML layout

```
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="inner-lines">
                <div class="content">
                    <p>CONTENT HERE</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    


     <div id = "up-down-nav">
        <a class="up-button" href="#">Up</a>
    <a class="down-button" href="#">Down</a>
 </div>
```

and the code

```
    var step = 25;
var scrolling = false;

// Wire up events for the 'scrollUp' link:
$(".down-button").bind("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Animates the scrollTop property by the specified
    // step.
    $(".content").animate({
        "margin-top" : "-=" + step + "px"
    });
});


$(".up-button").bind("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".content").animate({
        "margin-top" : "+=" + step + "px"
    });
});

function scrollContent(direction) {
    var amount = (direction === "up" ? "-=1px" : "+=1px");
    $(".content").animate({
        "margin-top" : amount
    }, 1, function() {
        if (scrolling) {
            scrollContent(direction);
        }
    });
}
```

I know this isn't working because ScrollTop is relating to the scroll of the doc but the doc doesn't scroll cos everything is positioned.

http://jsfiddle.net/s5mgX/1336/

I just can't figure out a good alternative (the design has no wiggle-room)

Margin-top animation means the div scolls past the bottom/top of the div and I want it to stop when there's no scroll left.

Any help would be great.

Comment: why are you using jQuery 1.4.4?

Comment: The Fiddle was based on an eg that already exists - can't actually find it but the jQuery version was already set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this: **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WnzKe/1/)**

```
$("#scrollUp").on("click", function (event) {
    // Animates the scrollTop property by the specified
    // step.
    $(".inner-lines").animate({
        scrollTop: "-=" + step + "px"
    });
     event.preventDefault();
})

$("#scrollDown").on("click", function (event) {
    $(".inner-lines").animate({
        scrollTop: "+=" + step + "px"
    });
     event.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: Thanks - can you explain why .inner-lines scrollTop is animated, and not .content?